# Split string at index field length or just before that if there is white space

Tags: javascript

I had to write a function to split a string that goes into a field if it(the string) were too long for the field, as it would disappear and be unreadable.

How's the code lookin' ?

```
function splitText(instr, fieldSize) //instr = string to split into two lines, fieldSize = the width(in characters)of the field where the string will be showing
{
    if(instr.length>fieldSize) // Check if String requires splitting
    { 
        //If Yes split
        var firstLine = instr.substring(0,fieldSize);
        var secondLine = instr.substring(fieldSize);
        //Check some arbitrary number of characters towards the end if there is whiye space(5) Obviously too much would not look too good on teh webSite
        var firstLeft = firstLine.substring(0,13);
        var firstRight = firstLine.substring(13);
        if(firstRight.indexOf(' ')>-1) 
            {
                //If There is white space, break the line at it
               instr = firstLeft+firstRight.substr(0,firstRight.indexOf(' '))+" \n"+firstRight.substr(firstRight.indexOf(' ')+1);
            }
        else
            //else just split the string, according to the field size
            instr = instr.substring(0,fieldSize)+"\n "+instr.substring(fieldSize);
        }

    return instr;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you just want to clip a string at a certain length but avoid clipping off at a word?

First off, your "arbitrary length" plus `indexOf` may clip more words than necessary because `indexOf` searches from the beginning of the string. Consider using `lastIndexOf` instead, which searches from the right. That way, the first space it encounters is the last in the string.

As for other things, your naming. `splitText` is very generic. We don't really know *how* it's splitting text or why. `instr` is a vague name. First time I read it, I thought it was "instruction". `firstLine` and `secondLine` aren't really "lines". They're just chunks of text. `firstLeft` and `firstRight`... there's second and more?

To reduce indents, especially nested conditions, you can "return early". Once you have the results you need, just `return`. Keeps the code relatively linear, and makes debugging less of a headache as you don't have to jump over huge blocks of unmet `if`s.

Anyways, your code can be simplified into:

```
function clipExcessText(text, limit){

  // If we didn't hit the limit, bail out. Nothing to do here.
  if(text.length <= limit) return text;

  // Now if we did, clip the string
  let validText = text.slice(0, limit);
  let excessText = text.slice(limit);

  // If we conveniently clipped after a word (the excess starts with
  // a space), then we just return the first half.
  if(excessText.charAt(0) === ' ') return validText;

  // We have clipped a word or after a space (excess doesn't start
  // with a space). Find the last space in the valid text and clip
  // at that position.
  return validText.slice(0, validText.lastIndexOf(' '));

}
```

Comment: Note that you may simply omit the first `if(text.length <= limit) return text;`.

Comment: @cFreed True. But if you do, you make the function do more than what's necessary.

Comment: I agree. But found it could be of negligable impact so reducing the code might be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is a bit off here, with the true case of the if being indented one extra level. The else case is missing its brackets, which is probably the cause of confusion.

```
    var firstRight = firstLine.substring(13);
    if(firstRight.indexOf(' ')>-1) 
        {
            //If There is white space, break the line at it
           instr = firstLeft+firstRight.substr(0,firstRight.indexOf(' '))+" \n"+firstRight.substr(firstRight.indexOf(' ')+1);
        }
    else
        //else just split the string, according to the field size
        instr = instr.substring(0,fieldSize)+"\n "+instr.substring(fieldSize);
    }
```

Aside from that, you call `firstRight.indexOf(' ')` three times, and you'd be better off placing this in a separate variable.